# How to append a 3d list and print its contents?

Tags: python, list, 3d, append

I want to create a list that has N lists, each of which will be filled with values that will be computed like this:

```
for i in range(R): for j in range(R): b.append(a[i]-a[j])
```

All the differences between i and j with step 2

I have this code:

```
b = []
for i in range(N):
    b.append([])
    for j in range(R):
        b[i].append([])
        for k in range(R,2):
            b[i][j].append(a[j]-a[k])
print b
```

Which gives:

`[[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]]`

Comment: Filled with what? Show how you want the array to look. Also your code is missing your `N`, `R`, and `a` variables

Comment: This is a part of "a" : (741.0, 0) (743.0, 0) (3386.0, 0) (284577.0, 0) (290611.0, 0) (300889.0, 3) (305256.0, 0) (917458.0, 0) (917905.0, 0) (917906.0, 0) (922187.0, 0)... with N=2 and R=40...

Comment: You should edit that into your post, also that's not a valid value for a variable, you would get a TypeError if you set that a value

Comment: i get no errors... a is a list that   has been appended before...

Comment: Edit your code to include that a value and you'll see what I mean. You can't set a = `741.0, 0) (743.0, 0) (3386.0, 0)`

Comment: [(741.0, 0), (743.0, 0), (3386.0, 0)]  this is it...but the way i had printed it showed it without []

Comment: Also you never answered the question of what you wnat it filled with

Comment: I want to create a list tha has N lists,each of them will be filled with values that will be computed like this: for i in range(R): for j in range(R): b.append(a[i]-a[j])...all the differences between i and j with step 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what N, R and a are, but I think the problem is in range(R,2). It should be range(0,R,2). Right now your last for loop doesn't do anything. I'm also not sure what 'a' is doing there.

```
N = 5
R = 4

b = []
for i in range(N):
    b.append([])
    for j in range(R):
        b[i].append([])
        for k in range(0,R,2):
            b[i][j].append(j - k)
print b
```

The code above returns the following:

```
[[[0, -2], [1, -1], [2, 0], [3, 1]], [[0, -2], [1, -1], [2, 0], [3, 1]], [[0, -2], [1, -1], [2, 0], [3, 1]], [[0, -2], [1, -1], [2, 0], [3, 1]], [[0, -2], [1, -1], [2, 0], [3, 1]]]
```

It's N lists of R lists of R/2 values. Is this what you're after?

Comment: yeah my description was missing some things...let me explain... "a" is a 2d list, here is a part of it:[(741.0, 0), (743.0, 0), (3386.0, 0), (284577.0, 0), (290611.0, 0), (300889.0, 3), (305256.0, 0), (917458.0, 0), (917905.0, 0)]...N=2 and R=40...i want to create b lists from a so that every b list will have the difference between a[j]-a[k]...

Comment: Hi Thanos, what's the length of a?

Comment: a[j] and a[k] are tuples. How would you like to subtract one tuple from the other? Are you maybe after (a[j][0]-a[k][0], a[j][1]-a[k][1])?

Comment: yeah you are right, i figured it out later...but they gave me the answer i needed above :) but thank you anyways!!!!